# C# and WPF loop counter value not changing when used in dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, loops, dispatcher

I've been coming across this weird issue and I can't seem to figure out a way to resolve it.

I'm writing a WPF application and I am loading values into a ListBox. To be specific this list box is displaying the Boot Order of a Client machine. So the List Box Item template holds 4 values. The New Sequence Number (what the boot order will be after the user changes it) the current (or Assigned) sequence Number (the order the machine is in now), the device name, and whether or not the device is enabled.

This data is loaded in a separate thread, so in order to display it in the listbox I use a dispatcher.

For the purposes of this question, there exists a List devices where Device is a class that holds the Assigned Sequence, and Device Name.

bootOrderListBox is the  ListBox UI Element.

The current loop is like so:

```
for(int i=0;i<devices.Count();i++)
{
    Device device = devices.ElementAt(i);
    int newSeqNum = (device.AssignedSequence == 0) ? 0 : i + 1;
        bool isEnabled = (device.AssignedSequence == 0) ? false : true;                                    

    Console.WriteLine("\t" + newSeqNum 
                      + "\t" + 
                      device.AssignedSequence 
                      + "\t" + device.DeviceName);
    bootOrderListBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)delegate
    {

        bootOrderListBox.Items.Add(new BootOrderDevice(device.AssignedSequence, 
                                                       newSeqNum,
                                                       device.DeviceName,
                                                       isEnabled));
    });
}
```

Now because of how this application is set-up, all my debugging is on a different machine than the one I develop on, however all console output has been redirected to a TextBox in the UI (also using a Dispatcher).

My problem is is that newSeqNum is a constant 1 value both in the "Console" and in the ListBox, but the code goes through the device list perfectly.

What could be causing this to happen, and what can I do to fix it?

My thoughts lead me to believe that when the Dispatcher runs it creates a new int with the default value on the separate thread, or something like that.

Many thanks.

========================Update====================================================

The output in the Listbox (and in console) looks like:

New Sequence  Assigned Sequence Device Name

1    2     Diskette Drive:1

1    1     USB Storage Device:3

1    3     Onboard NIC:5

1    4     Internal HDD:2

1    5     CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive:4

It definitely gets the different devices from the list.

========================Update 2==================================================
The ListBox XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="bootOrderListBox"
             Grid.Row="2"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Name="newSequenceTextBlock"
                               Text="{Binding Path=NewSequence}"
                               Margin="10,2,2,2" />
                    <TextBlock Name="assignedSequenceTextBlock"
                               Text="{Binding Path=AssignedSequence}"
                               Margin="50,2,2,2" />
                    <TextBlock Name="deviceNameTextBlock"
                               Text="{Binding Path=DeviceName}"
                               Margin="30,2,2,2" />
                    <CheckBox Name="isEnabledCheckBox"
                              IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}"
                              Margin="10,2,2,2" 
                              Checked="isEnabledCheckBox_Checked"
                              Unchecked="isEnabledCheckBox_Unchecked"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The BootOrderDevice class that it binds to:

```
public class BootOrderDevice
{
        public int AssignedSequence { get; set; }

        public int NewSequence { get; set; }

        public string DeviceName { get; set; }

        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

        public BootOrderDevice(int assSequence, int newSequence, string deviceName, bool isEnabled)
        {
            AssignedSequence = assSequence;
            NewSequence = newSequence;
            DeviceName = deviceName;
            IsEnabled = isEnabled;
        }
    }
```

Comment: if `newSeqNum == 1` in the each loop cycle - then `Device device = devices.ElementAt(i)` must return the same `device` instance, what you see in console output, a dump for different devices or for the same

Comment: BTW, do you posted code without ANY modifications???

Comment: That's copy and pasted from my application. The BootOrderDevice class was recently added to bind with the ListBoxItemTemplate. I'm planning on removing the device class in the future.

Comment: I think we're going to have to see how you're displaying the Assigned Sequence. Is it part of a template or are you overriding ToString()?

Comment: is there something goofy where device.AssignedSequence is always 0 the first time you call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this has something to do with closure and value capture. Try moving newSeqNum declaration outside of the for loop.

Comment: that seems like it would be the case for the dispatch call, but the console.writeline should be right in that case, wouldn't it?

Comment: Actually the Console.WriteLine() statement gets redirected to a TextStreamWriter that uses a dispatcher to write to a TextBox in the UI

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can see newSeqNum being 1 is because of this:

```
int newSeqNum = (device.AssignedSequence == 0) ? 0 : i + 1;
```

does the compiler see that as:

```
int newSeqNum = ((device.AssignedSequence == 0) ? 0 : i) + 1;
```

which would always give you 1 if assigned sequence was 0.

or does the compiler see that as:

```
int newSeqNum = (device.AssignedSequence == 0) ? 0 : (i + 1);
```

Comment: Yes that's what I'm intending. I want new sequence to be 1-5 ascending.

Comment: But each loop cycle `i` is incremented so newSeqNum would not be `1` as now but `==i` instead of `i+1` as expected, something wrong...

Comment: BTW your assumption regarding "how compiler sees" is wrong,please see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.100).aspx). Basically all what after `:` is a single expresion which evaluates and becomes a result